# LuaTeX callback for single line captions

Tags: captions, luatex, callback

I am using LuaTeX and its associated callbacks (`pre_linebreak_filter`, `post_linebreak_filter` and `mlist_to_hlist`) to analyze lines and paragraphs during typesetting of a pdf document. This works fine but I encountered a problem with figure captions.

For a longer caption that is broken into multiple lines, everything works as expected. `pre_linebreak_filter` reports the full text, while `post_linebreak_filter` reports a `vlist` with the individual lines.

If the caption is short enough to fit into a single line (i.e. no line breaking is needed) the processing of the caption **does not generate any callbacks**. This leads to my questions:

1. Is this behavior intended, which would be in contrast to other single-line content, such as title or author lines, which DO generate these callbacks?
2. How am I able to get to know that a single-line caption is processed?

**PS**: Note that the caption content shows up in the output assembly callback of `pre_output_filter`. However, paragraph affiliation information is already lost at this stage. Thus, this does not help me.

**PPS**: An example would be just to add

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{ FILENAME }
  \caption{ TEXT }
\end{figure}
```

in an ordinary article with TEXT fitting either in a single line or not. The callbacks are linked via the following code in the TeX source

```
\directlua{ luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", pre_callback, "pre_callback") }
\directlua{ luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter", post_callback, "post_callback") }
```

In a separate Lua file, the following functions process the callbacks

```lua
pre_callback = function (head)
  texio.write_nl("PRE CALLED")
  -- Recursive inspection of head
end

post_callback = function (head)
  texio.write_nl("POST CALLED")
  -- Recursive inspection of head
end
```

For both short and long caption texts, both `pre_linebreak_filter` and `post_linebreak_filter` report the image itself (in form of `whatsit` nodes with subtypes 41, 40, 42, 14) and output "CALLED" in the log file. But ONLY for the long caption, the caption text itself is reported in separate callbacks (thus "PRE CALLED" and "POST CALLED" appear twice in log file). For a short caption, no callback is raised for the caption text and "PRE CALLED", as well as "POST CALLED" appear only once.

**PPPS**: I am using LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> with LuaTeX 0.76.0.

Comment: Could you please add an example with the `callback`s' code? Thanks.

Comment: I added additional code that shows how I register the LuaTeX callbacks and the actual Lua code itself.

Comment: The definition of `\@makecaption` in the `article` class doesn't make TeX into starting a paragraph when the caption fits in one line, because it does `\hbox to \hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}` (where `\@tempboxa` stores the caption text).

Comment: @egreg

While I am moderatly familiar with LuaTeX, I am fairly unknowlegable about actual TeX macro programming. Thus, I am not able to understand the implications of this observation. Does this mean that the caption is packed into an hbox?

In this case, it should be possible to gain information about the caption with the `hpack` callback. But at the same time requires some filtering effort to remove other `hpack` spam.

Comment: @ThomasAuzinger When you do `\hbox{...}` in vertical mode, no paragraph is started. I'm sure there's a suitable callback that applies also in this case and this one you should use; or you should change `\@makecaption` so that it makes a paragraph also in the “fit in one line” case, say `{\centering\unhbox\@tempboxa\par}`.

Comment: I understand. I will try to obtain the caption information via a different callback and report on my progress. Thank you.

Comment: You need to register the function both in the ``pre_linebreak_filter`` and the ``hpack_filter`` callback.
This combination is quite common, for instance in Context, both are fused into the ``mvlbuilders`` node processor and not even available separately unless you resort to Dirty Tricks™.

Comment: @phg Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 8):

> If the caption is short enough to fit into a single line (i.e. no line
>   breaking is needed) the processing of the caption does not generate any
>   callbacks.

As explained by /u/egreg in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146168/luatex-callback-for-single-line-captions?noredirect=1#comment331278_146168),
the difference is that in some cases, no paragraph is created.
For this reason the line break algorithm is not invoked on the
horizontal list;
consequently, `pre_linebreak_filter` callback is not triggered.
You can observe this difference by putting text into a hbox or vbox:

```
\hbox {Horizontal list only, without line break.}         \par
\vbox {Vertical list, triggers the line break mechanism.} \par
```

Only the second line is a affected by line breaking.

> Is this behavior intended, which would be in contrast to other
>   single-line content, such as title or author lines, which DO generate
>   these callbacks?

The behavior is indeed intended:
LuaTeX offers another callback -- the `hpack_filter` -- that is
[invoked whenever TeX packages an hbox](https://github.com/pgundlach/LuaTeX/blob/master/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/packaging.w#L1223).
You can use it the same way as the `pre_linebreak_filter`,
although the callback receives further arguments on the Lua side that
contain information about the state TeX is presently in.

---

To illustrate the problem I add some example code (tested with Luatex
0.78.2).
First the Lua file; its file name should differ from the TeX code below
only in the extension:

```lua
local traverse_nodes      = node.traverse
local iowrite             = io.write
local tableconcat         = table.concat
local utfchar             = unicode.utf8.char

local nodecodes           = table.mirrored (node.types())
local glyph_t             = nodecodes.glyph
local glue_t              = nodecodes.glue

local cbk = function (hd, group, size, pack)
  --[[--
    Demo function collecting text from glyph nodes in the list starting
    with ``hd``, printing them to stdout.
  --]]--
  local text = {
    "\n["
    .. (group == "" and "par" or group)
    --- the line below shows more info from the hpack_filter context
    --.. (size and (":" .. tostring (size) .. ":" .. pack) or "")
    .. "] "
  }
  for n in traverse_nodes (hd) do
    local ntype = n.id
    if ntype == glyph_t then
      text [#text + 1] = utfchar (n.char)
    elseif ntype == glue_t then
      text [#text + 1] = " "
    else -- print node type
      text [#text + 1] = "<" .. nodecodes [ntype] .. ":" .. tostring (n.subtype) .. ">"
    end
  end

  text [#text + 1] = "\n"
  iowrite (tableconcat (text))
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback ("pre_linebreak_filter", cbk, "document.nodeprinter")
luatexbase.add_to_callback ("hpack_filter",         cbk, "document.nodeprinter")
```

And some Latex code that shows different cases:

```
\documentclass    {scrartcl}
\usepackage       {luatexbase}
\RequireLuaModule {lualibs}
\directlua        {dofile "\jobname.lua"}

\begin {document}

  \hbox {Horizontal list only, without line break.}         \par
  \vbox {Vertical list, triggers the line break mechanism.} \par

  \begin {figure}
    \input ward
    \caption {Some brief caption.} %% same as with the hbox above
  \end {figure}

  This is some \hbox{ordinary} paragraph material.

\end {document}
```

You can also clone the code conveniently bundled as
[a gist](https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/8767389).

---

Ordinarily, when processing text nodes you want to register your
function in both callbacks.
There are some caveats, though.

The main problem affects the order of execution:
The `hpack_filter`s are *called in a separate step prior to handing
over the paragraph to the line breaking mechanism*.
For instance, in the following snippet:

```
This is some \hbox{ordinary} paragraph material.
```

the hbox containing the text “ordinary” is processed in the
`hpack_filter` before the rest of the text is passed to the
`pre_linebreak_filter`.
Depending on what you want to achieve, this can end up in a mess.

The solution to this problem is to not rely on the `hpack_filter` and
traverse the node lists recursively, e. g.:

```lua
local traverse_nodes      = node.traverse
local iowrite             = io.write
local stringformat        = string.format
local stringrep           = string.rep
local nodelength          = node.length
local count_nodes         = node.count

local nodecodes           = table.mirrored (node.types())
local hlist_t             = nodecodes.hlist
local vlist_t             = nodecodes.vlist

local rec_cbk rec_cbk = function (hd, _, depth, where)
  --[[--
    Recursively walk a paragraph node list and print basic info.
  --]]--
  if not depth then
    iowrite "\n"
    depth = 1
    where = "par"
  end
  iowrite (stringrep (" ", depth) ..
           stringformat ("[%s:%d] %d nodes, %d glyphs\n",
                         where, depth,
                         nodelength (hd),
                         count_nodes (glyph_t, hd)))
  for n in traverse_nodes (hd) do
    local ntype = n.id
    if ntype == vlist_t then
      rec_cbk (n.head, nil, depth + 1, "vbox")
    elseif ntype == hlist_t then
      rec_cbk (n.head, nil, depth + 1, "hbox")
      --- else pass
    end
  end
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback ("pre_linebreak_filter", rec_cbk, "document.recursenodes")
```

Use this code as above and typeset something slightly more complex:

```
  This is some \vbox {\hbox {significantly}
                      \hbox {less}
                      \hbox {ordinary}} paragraph material.
```

The hbox’ed and vbox’ed material will now be encountered in its natural
order.

Unfortunately this is not an option if you want to process the float
captions.
Also, the combined use of `pre_linebreak_filter` and `hpack_filter`
usually results in better performance, though.